# Can the Java Method object be compared by identity (ie. ==) or do I have to use equals()?

Tags: java, reflection, equality, comparison-operators

In Java, can instances of the `java.lang.reflect.Method` object be compared by identity (ie. ==) or do I have to use equals()?

Comment: You can do either - it depends what you are trying to achieve. The semantics of  `Method.equals()` are explained in [the javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: I believe this question has been incorrectly closed. The OP is asking about the `java.lang.reflect.Method` class, not about generic == vs equals(), much the same as with the `java.lang.Class` class.

Comment: @Magnamag the case is the same. Use `equals` for object references, not `==`. If you want to check if you can use `==`, write a test for it. Thanks for let the site be polluted with these bad questions...

Comment: Regarding the question itself, it's always better to use the `.equals()` method. This way equality always has the semantics explained in the `java.lang.reflect.Method.equals()` javadocs.

Comment: @Luiggi I completely agree! See my other comment ;)

Comment: @Magnamag whatever, the question is open...

Comment: @Luiggi It's a site for questions, and we're not supposed to judge begginers who came here, even if they ask things we consider straightforward or extremely simple. The OP hasn't asked why a circle has no sharp corners or why the moon is round. Instead he asked a specific question about equality between instances of a specific class of the Java Language. Please don't be so hurried in applying the little piece of power you were given by this site.

Comment: @Magnamag a question that has been asked before, so the question should be closed as a duplicate. Period.

Comment: @Magnamag I cannot because it was reopened... Again, thanks for letting the site be polluted :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I'm with Magnamag... it's not the same question.

Comment: @Luiggi: Agree with @Magnamag. In no way, the question was about general use of == vs. equals(), but specifically the `java.lang.reflect.Method` object. Sorry for making that not clear enough, will edit question

Comment: Well.. read the JavaDoc, and if still not convinced, create a test, just like the answer did... Still, not a good question.

Comment: @Luiggi: I disagree. The Javadoc of Method.equals unfortunately proves no info. And to quote Magnamag: "it could be justified to assume that there exists only one instance of each Method - similar to Class objects, which are created exactly once in the JVM" -- with a test I finally came to the conclusion of the answer, but I could would not have needed to test that if I had found the answer on the Internet.

Comment: @JRA_TLL use the `equals` method. Example aboves uses a single `ClassLoader`. If you load the same class using different `ClassLoader`s and use `==` to compare two instances of the same `Method`, you will get a big giant `false`. Then again, use `equals` over `==` for object reference comparison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question does not refer to the difference between `==` and `equals` in general, but refers to `java.lang.reflect.Method` instances in particular.

It is a reasonable question, because it could be justified to assume that there exists only *one instance* of each `Method` - similar to `Class` objects, which are created exactly *once* in the JVM.

However, this is not the case: Two `Method` objects may be `equal`, even though they are not *identical*, as can be seen in this example (it also does the comparison for `Class` objects, to emphasize that these indeed *are* identical)

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class MethodEquals
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        checkMethods();
        checkClasses();
    }

    static void checkMethods() throws Exception
    {
        Method m0 = MethodEquals.class.getMethod("exampleMethod", int.class);
        Method m1 = MethodEquals.class.getMethod("exampleMethod", int.class);

        boolean identical = (m0 == m1);
        boolean equal = m0.equals(m1);

        System.out.println("Methods: "+(identical == equal)); // prints "false"
    }

    static void checkClasses() throws Exception
    {
        Class<?> c0 = Class.forName("stackoverflow.MethodEquals");
        Class<?> c1 = Class.forName("stackoverflow.MethodEquals");

        boolean identical = (c0 == c1);
        boolean equal = c0.equals(c1);

        System.out.println("Classes: "+(identical == equal)); // prints "true"
    }

    public float exampleMethod(int i)
    {
        return 42.0f;
    }
}
```

Comment: The _real_ answer is the return of the `exampleMethod`.

Comment: It is a reasonable question. i don't know why some proud user like Luiggi judges so fast?